# School system for primitives

Tags: alternate-history

What is the most basic type of civilization which can sustain a school system where children spend 12 to 14 hours each day in school where they learn and develop attributes instead of culuture.

A school based on survival and well being of the body and mind instead of a school based on learning how to make money.

Things like:

Math > becomes logic and imagination

Story > becomes journaling and researching

Language > becomes listening and problem solving

Religion > becomes patience and pain tolerance

And other skills are also developed like apnea training for diving, climbing and first aid.

Could such a school system be developed in  tribes which still live in huts?

Comment: LIfe? As in, life by pre-fire cavemen even, would qualify for this. You would need the edit your exact opinion of what constitutes "money","math", etc., but that is *exactly* what a primitive culture does with its time. Learn how to survive to become functional adults.

Comment: You mean epicureanism? Oh wait, that's cululture, too, right. ;) Might one ask why you're knocking *culture*, when you don't want *greed*? (Agreed on disregarding religion, which inevitably turns out as destructive on culture.)

Comment: "develop attributes instead of culuture." --> or "develop spelling instead of culture". ;-)

Comment: Whatever the students are learning IS your culture, especially if they are learning it 14 hours a day. Also ">" means greater than which makes your entire concept really difficult to understand.

Comment: I am happy that I was never in school for 12+ hours a day... The full day school I was in (in Germany) started at 8am and ended at 4pm... And the teachers should not give homework for days where we had school that long (most of them did anyway when we had more than one day till the next class with them....). IMO sending kids to school for 14 hrs a day isn't healthy in any culture. Especially since many primitive cultures don't know a weekend. Plus what you describe is more physical almost like a boot camp...

Answer (score 22):

#### "Sit down and listen to the stories of the elders" IS school in these societies

An example is ["The dreaming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreaming), a collection of Australian Aboriginal teachings past orally from elder to child. These teachings contained useful information for those children to use later in life. Eg "This tree's roots are edible", "You can rehydrate from this plants sap if desperate", "don't swim in this lake it has crocodiles", etc. Each story was owned by the local peoples and there is considerable variation around the continent, and my high level summary can't do the concept justice, but it obviously had some merit as it basically allowed a race of people to survive for ~100,000 years in the brutal Australian Outback on oral history alone.

Learning by doing is a part of school, these skills need practice, and just because the bulk of those 12-14 hours is spent putting what they heard into action doesn't mean it doesn't count as "school".

Teaching children life skills counts as schooling even if there are no desks and chairs involved.

Comment: One notes that wrapping up one's education in stories is a good way to improve the pupil's retention.

Answer (score 15):

### Not naturally.

The reason why tribal peoples don't have schools (or really any kind of high philosophy/science) is that **most of their time is occupied in surviving.** This raises two problems:

1. While, as @Tristan mentioned, "primitive" civilizations often have more free time than early industrial ones, it's sporadic and often interrupted. Because of this, neither the adults nor the children will be able to spend "12 to 14 hours each day" in school.
2. By keeping the kids in school all day, they can't learn the practical skills necessary to survive. Being able to read and write is nice, but it won't help you kill a wild boar.

As a result, while things like missionary schools can work quite well (provided that the kids aren't kept in school for "12 to 14 hours each day"), **tribes will not develop schools on their own.** That takes a certain amount of stability (and therefore extra time) which they simply don't yet have.

The closest things that most "primitive" cultures have to this is story time, where elders tell/teach children stories of various theological, ethical, and historical import. The important thing to note is that *while useful for metaphysical/ethical topics, these do not teach things like math*.

Comment: I'd add a third reason, even if it's partially covered by the other two. Kids will help out with the survival. They can gather food, or wood, build fires, scout, or join and help hunts, etc. So, they will be occupied with survival but also learn on the go.

Comment: Not to mention schools rely on having a large number of children of the same age, which a small society will not have. You also need specialized labor, schools don't make sense in you live in a society without specialized labor. children can learn any skill form anyone in small societies.

Comment: 1: hunter gatherers and subsistence farmers actually have lots of free time. More than most workers in early industrial economies, and in some cases, even than many workers in e.g. the US

Comment: @Tristan True. My point isn't so much that they don't have free time at all (they do; that's why missionary schools work) so much as that (a) "12 to 14 hours each day" is impractical, and (b) the chances that they can come up with analytical logic, math, and reading/writing in the first place while they remain at their level of civilization are *incredibly* small.

Comment: well, 12-14 hours a day of education isn't really practical in any society. I'd also question whether it's true that such societies *can't* come up with such knowledge, so much as that they don't have any incentive to develop it because those fields of study evolved to handle problems specific to a very different society which has private property and formal debts, rather than communal living

Answer (score 7):

The archaeologist stepped out of the time machine, and asked the Neanderthal how she teaches the children.

"The children sit with me while I knap a knife, and we sing together the song of flint and knives," she said. "I carve a comb and a spear, and we sing the songs of wood and ivory. I wash them and comb their hair and we sing the washing song. We walk for days, as we sing the songs of paths across rivers, valleys, mountains and plains. I cannot sing while I hunt, but they see the adults hunt in the day and at night we sing the hunting songs. Sometimes we sing the songs of ancestors who prospered by living well or who suffered from wrongdoing. In this way the children learn all things. They will remember the songs, and no-one who sings will ever be lost in the wilderness or forget how to live."

Answer (score 4):

### Thousands of Years From Now

*What* you want to teach is a deal-killer. Utopia questions are painful because they rely on facts not in evidence. Here's your problem: the purpose of school is to allow individuals to either compete amongst themselves or to better permit the nation to compete with other nations. All utopic questions are, IMO, invalid because they insist that the competition can be removed.

Except that it's 100% contrary to what we know about *evolution.*

- In ancient days, whether before the invention of writing or after, primary schooling was word-of-mouth, a passing of skills and culture based on the needs of the civilization and its understanding of the world around it. It was intrinsically religious in nature.

*You want tribes but you don't want religion. What humanity doesn't know it mystifies. Look at the absolute belief today's younger generation has in Dark Matter. Dark Matter is a mathematical band-aid used to explain empirical evidence today's mathematical models cannot predict. We'll either physically discover it or, more likely, improve our mathematical models to better express the Universe. Because invisible mass should be hard for anyone to swallow. Nevertheless, the younger generation believes in it as if they could scoop up a pound and sift it through their fingers anytime they wanted. That's religion — it's just been upgraded for the 21st century.*

- As civilizations became more complex, the need to pass necessary skills along to the next generation evolved. This was primarily done either within families or through apprenticeships with practiced craftsmen.
- As government became more complex, trade unions (aka guilds) formed for everything from taxation to representation to certification to protection of intellectual rights... The development of law almost goes hand-in-hand with the development of trade unions.

*Here is where there's enough information that must be conveyed to a child to justify day-long education. Skills in literacy, mathematics, science, law/government, even warfare... Maybe not starting in kindergarten, but it's possible here — but not in any way, shape, or form conforming to your list of what the basic skill sets will become.*

- Your earliest formal schools are thought to be in China.

> According to legendary accounts, the rulers Yao and Shun (ca. 24th-23rd century BC) established the first schools. The first education system was created in Xia dynasty (2076–1600 BC). During Xia dynasty, government built schools to educate aristocrats about rituals, literature and archery (important for ancient Chinese aristocrats). ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_education))

*But you can see the problem: those schools are not teaching in a manner you want to teach*

**Practical answer:** 2,000 B.C. So long as you ignore everything you want to do to education and stick to the basic question, "what's the earliest we can assume to have formal schooling for children during the day?"

But as long as you stick with changing education such that it's...

> A school based on survival and well being of the body and mind instead of a school based on learning how to make money.

That requires the mythical post-scarcity society that has, somehow, proven to itself entirely that God does not exist.

***Thousands of years from now.***

Comment: The purpose of school is what you make it to be. If the "younger generation believes in Dark Matter", that is because they grow up in a society where religious stupidity is the accepted norm, and nobody dares to challenge it. Where nobody asks for rigourous explanations.

Comment: @Karl You know, it's the funniest thing, but "religious stupidity" is what motivated thousands of years of art, government, law, and provided hope for billions over time during crises where no one could understand what was happening. It's true that religion as a tool has been used for great evil - but its contemplation taught many how to think. You're ability to judge religion exists because of religion. You may not be religious yourself, but your contempt is not only misplaced - it might be ignorant.

Comment: Schools existed for a variety of purposes and competition makes up only a small part of that. Most of the time schools existed to teach basic skills in a system full of specialists.

Comment: @John I'm curious to know how competition makes up only a small part of education. Even in the most trivial case, you're competing with Mother Nature to survive.

Comment: My contempt was on religious *stupidity*. I don't know if religions can survive without it, from what I see, trying makes them struggle badly. And  wether religion has helped humans to develop in the past is an old debate, but it certainly hasn't in the last 300 years.

Comment: Why would schools require a lack of religion? I don't see the OP requiring this; patience and pain resistance could well be skills justified on religious basis. Of course religion requires more than a set of _skills_, but _knowledge_ of religion could well be thought to be best kept out of school. Also, you assume a post-scarcity society is required, but why not a pre-scarcity society? Sure, many "primitive" peoples have to toil to survive, but an isolated group living by a rainforest river, say, wouldn't need to work much to live in abundance, provided they avoid overpopulation.

Comment: @EdvinW Your question about religion is one only the OP can answer. My interpretation of the question is that religion was being replaced in the traditional utopia model. I assume a post-scarcity model because I believe the shift from making money (the demand for productivity) to a school based on body & mind (a luxury) requires is. The OP's inclusion of survival is nonsensical as any effort to survive is the demand for productivity, most notably for the excess of resources needed to expand even knowledge.